# Is there a way to bring back the full status bar in Safari 9?

Tags: safari, ios

Contrary to what Apple (or a Google search) seems to think, I don't want a more minimal status bar—I want one that stays in place, is the same height and width at all times, and doesn't distract me by flashing in and out.  Much like I've had through all of Safari's existence up until now.

Now it's changed, and I can't find a setting to move it back.  Is there another option (perhaps via Terminal magic) that can unlock a more "classic" feel to the status bar?

Comment: We do have Cmd/num to go directly to a tab, though - you win some, you lose some ;-) I starred & +1'ed this because I'd like my bar back too, not just floating over some blurry background. Not good on the eye.

Comment: Didn't know about that new feature—thanks for commenting!

Comment: They've removed it for good. (At least in this version) I've always liked it too, but don't think about it much now.

Comment: Are you on El Capitan or Yosemite?

Comment: Well, based on the bounty it seems some enterprising coder has 4 days to write an extension!

Comment: @Arc676 El Capitan here.

Comment: Have you tried just going to customize toolbar? I did that and it have all I want and it doesn't hide. I haven't put it as an answer incase you say yes. If not, it's simple enough and I can tell you how. I'm not sure what you want on it...mine doesn't hide, I have print, send to, fonts, favs, history, autofill, home

Comment: @gracey209 This is about the status bar on the bottom; not the address bar on top.  If you have any information on that, please feel free to add an answer!

Comment: Oh ok. I don't even show a status bar on the bottom of mine. Not sure what you're referring to. You mean the thing showing file type, etc? That's on top of mine...

Comment: @gracey209 Command / will make it appear.  Current version only shows when you hover over links, however.

Comment: Let me see....ill check it out.

Comment: Under view, do you have hide status bar unchecked? I see what you mean... It floats away when not in use

Comment: That's the one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let's go through the options here:

- `defaults write com.apple.Safari ShowStatusBar -boolean true`

  - No effect.
- [Minimal status bar extension](http://visnup.github.io/Minimal-Status-Bar/)

  - It auto hides.
- [Ultimate status bar extension](http://ultimatestatusbar.com)

  - Yup, auto hides too.
- [Statusbar-lite](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.zhaomiing.statusbar-lite-CA9Y298CEX)

  - Guess what? :/

While searching around though, I found a *great deal* of people asking how they force the bar to autohide. It's a [common complaint](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/02/25/minimal-status-bar-safari-extension/) in editorials as well, and seems to be the one constant of all the Safari extensions.

After an extensive search - what you're looking for does not exist at this time :(

<sub><sub>Hardly the first time Apple has taken away control from a user, either...</sub></sub>

### Tl;dr: Apologies, but it's time to let it go - it's gone.

[image]

### HOWEVER....

One of the extensions I found is open source and appears to be easily editable. Specifically, [this one](https://github.com/visnup/Minimal-Status-Bar), and by removing a line of JS, I can force the bar to stay on the screen, and replace it with blank text (so it looks correctly).

Here's the thing, it's still just an overlay on top of the page, it's not a part of the safari "window" as the old status bar could be, and doesn't show all of the same information either.

[Here's what the effect looks like](https://i.imgur.com/yB3EgRu.gifv)

[And here's the extension package](https://github.com/Karunamon/Minimal-Status-Bar/releases/download/1.18-1/Minimal-Status-Bar.safariextension.zip). You can see the [changes made from the official release to make this possible](https://github.com/visnup/Minimal-Status-Bar/compare/master...Karunamon:master) as well.

Installing this requires jumping through an extra hoop since I'm not a registered Apple dev, so here's what you need to do.

1. Download and extract the package.
2. In Safari, go to Preferences -> Advanced
3. Check the "Show Develop menu in menu bar" box
4. In the newly added menu bar item, click on "Show Extension Builder"
5. Click on the plus sign in the bottom left of the new window and hit "Add extension"
6. Navigate to where you unzipped the .safariextension folder
7. Accept the security warning
8. Reload any open webpages

Usual disclaimers apply, your mileage may vary, void where prohibited, kids eat free, etc.

Comment: I like what I'm seeing in the sample.  When you say it "doesn't show all of the same information", what items are left out?

Comment: Basically all you're going to see in there is link info when you roll over one. I did the mod on my work machine, so I'll upload the actual extension package on Monday when I get back to that computer :)

Comment: @Kaji just updated it with the download/install instructions. Hope this helps!

Comment: Working pretty well so far.  On some pages it's hiding the bottom-most items a bit, but not having things flashing in and out is much appreciated.  Thanks!